# How to display Gridview in SapUI5

Tags: html, sapui5

I am currently a beginner in SapUI5 and want to display images in a **gridview** ?

can anyone please help with this

Comment: In the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54653559/5846045), you can add `sap.m.Image` as a content of the `CustomListItem`. Then you have "images in a gridview"

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to create a image and then place it in a grid layout:

```
var oImage = new sap.ui.commons.Image("image");
oImage.setSrc("source of image");
oImage.setTooltip("tooltip");
oImage.placeAt("grid layout");
```

Answer (score 0):

first create one grid layout

```
var oLayout2 = new sap.ui.commons.form.GridLayout("L2");
```

then create one image

and `setLayoutData` :