# Arrange list items in grid

Tags: sapui5

What I want to do is to arrange the list items (coming from a binding) in a grid with columns. Here is my code:

```xml
<l:Grid
  defaultSpan="L3 M4 S6"
  class="sapUiSmallMarginTop"
>
  <m:List
    mode="None"
    items="{tickets>children}"
  >
    <m:CustomListItem>
      <m:HBox>
        <core:Icon
          size="2rem"
          src="sap-icon://circle-task-2"
          class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom color-green" 
          visible="{= ${tickets>status} === 'resolved'}"
          tooltip="{i18n>ticket.status.resolved}"
        />
        <core:Icon
          size="2rem"
          src="sap-icon://circle-task-2"
          class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom color-red"
          visible="{= ${tickets>status} === 'open'}"
          tooltip="{i18n>ticket.status.open}"
        />
        <m:VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom">
          <m:Link
            text="#{tickets>referenceNumber}"
            target="{tickets>id}"
            press="handleChildRecordPress"
          />
          <m:Label text="{
            path: 'tickets>unitID',
            formatter: '.formatUnit'
          }"/>
        </m:VBox>
      </m:HBox>
      <m:layoutData>
        <l:GridData span="L12 M12 S12" />
      </m:layoutData>
    </m:CustomListItem>
  </m:List>
</l:Grid>
```

But it only shows one item per row and not multiple. How can I display multiple items in a row?

This is how it looks now, what I want is to show like 3 or 4 items in a row (responsive would be nice)

[image]

Comment: `tnt.BoxContainer` is replaced by `f.GridList` which is [now publicly available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54653559/5846045).

Answer (score 2):

UI5 **1.60** introduces a new control named `sap.f.GridList`<sup>[API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.f.GridList)</sup> that combines functionalities of `sap.m.ListBase` (e.g. `growing`) with the ability to display list items in a grid layout (`display: grid` in CSS internally).

```xml
<f:GridList xmlns:f="sap.f"
  class="sapUxAPObjectPageSubSectionAlignContent"
  items="..."
>
  <f:customLayout>
    <cssgrid:GridBoxLayout xmlns:cssgrid="sap.ui.layout.cssgrid" boxesPerRowConfig="XL7 L4 M3 S1" />
  </f:customLayout>
  <f:items>
    <!-- m.CustomListItem, m.StandardListItem, etc.. -->
  </f:items>
</f:GridList>
```

The custom layout `GridBoxLayout`<sup>[API](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.cssgrid.GridBoxLayout)</sup> enables displaying the grid items in a responsive way, which can be configured via `boxPerRowConfig` and `boxMinWidth` properties.

[image: openui5 sapui5 grid list]
<sup>Source: https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.f.sample.GridListBoxContainer/preview</sup>

---

**Note:** `sap.f.GridList` currently has dependencies to `sap.m`, `sap.f`, and `sap.ui.layout`. Add them to the list of dependencies, e.g. in the app descriptor, so that those libraries can be loaded in parallel with other dependent libs asynchronously:

```json
"sap.ui5": {
  "dependencies": {
    "libs": {
      "sap.ui.core": {},
      "sap.m": {},
      "sap.f": {},
      "sap.ui.layout": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thing what you need is a [sap.m.Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview) not a Grid, neither a List